# Create a shortcut to a folder on the desktop 13.04

Tags: windows, filesystem, shortcuts

I am looking to create a shortcut either in the explorer or on my desktop to the /host/users/Harry/ folder so I can access my windows partition easily, it is a hassle to go through the filesystem each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the explorer and browse to the folder you want to bookmark (/host/users/Harry/). Press Ctrl+D to bookmark the folder. It will show up in the left pane of the explorer.

P.S. In Ubuntu, the explorer is called Nautilus.

Answer (score 5):

Open files, right click the folder that you want, and click on Make Link,

[image]

once done, move the newly created link to the desktop

[image]